# How to make white on transparent image using Carrierwave Image magick

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave with ImageMagick library and i want to convert a image as white on transparent

My uploader.rb

```
class IconUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  DIMENSIONS = [48,48]

  process :white_transparent

  def white_transparent
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.transparent("#ffffff")
        cmd.channel "a"
        cmd.separate
        cmd.negate
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def filename
    "notification_icon.png"
  end
end
```

I tried the above and i got a "black on white" image as below
[image]

I need to convert the image like this [image]

To the images as mentioned below

[image]

I want to use converted image as notification icon in Android.

Kindly help.

Comment: What was the starting image? And what output were you hoping for?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated my question.

Comment: So you want the `6` to become transparent and the red to become white?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want the red to become transparent. Updated again for clear understanding.

Comment: That is rather hard because if you enlarge the `M` a lot you will see it has green/cyan pixels at the edges, and that even the greyish pixels are not really grey and that the transparency layer is useless.